# Visual FoxPro 9 C# OleDbAdapter Insert - Feature is Not Available

Tags: c#, oledb, visual-foxpro, foxpro

How do I insert into a FoxPro table with a primary key whose default value is`newid("tablename")` using [Microsoft's OLE DB Provider for Visual Foxpro 9.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839)?

I have two tables, one where the primary key has a default value of `newid("tablename")`, and the other whose data type is set to `Integer (AutoInc)`.

When I try to run the same `insert` command on the `newid` table, I get the following `OleDbException`:

`Feature is not available`

When I run `insert` on the table with `Integer (AutoInc)` as the primary key, it works.

Here is the code I am trying to execute:

```cs
public void InsertData()
{
    using(var connectionHandler = new OleDbConnection("Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=\"C:\\path\\to\\db.dbc\";"))
    {
        var insertStatement = @"INSERT INTO mytable (mycol) values (?)";

        var insertCommand = new OleDbCommand(insertStatement, connectionHandler);

        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("mycol", OleDbType.Char).Value="blue";

        connectionHandler.Open();
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connectionHandler.Close();
    }
}
```

Is there any reason OLE would not be able to execute an `insert` because of this `newid()` default value?

---

Another case that fixes my issue is if I manually specify an `id` in the `insert` clause. ex:

```
var insertStatement = @"INSERT INTO mytable (id, mycol) values (?, ?)";
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 199;
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("mycol", OleDbType.Char).Value = "blue";
```

Additionally, I am able to run a `select * from tablename` on this table.

`select` snippet:

```
public DataTable GetData()
{
    var myData = new DataTable();

    using(var connectionHandler = new OleDbConnection("Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=\"C:\\path\\to\\db.dbc\";"))
    {       
        var da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        var mySQL = "select * from mytable";

        var myQuery = new OleDbCommand(mySQL, connectionHandler);
        connectionHandler.Open();

        da.SelectCommand = myQuery;

        da.Fill(myData);

        connectionHandler.Close();
    }

    return myData;
}
```

`newid()` SP:

```
function newId
parameter thisdbf
regional keynm, newkey, cOldSelect, lDone
keynm=padr(upper(thisdbf),50)
cOldSelect=alias()
lDone=.f.
do while not lDone
    select keyvalue from main!idkeys where keyname=keynm into array akey
    if _tally=0
        insert into main!idkeys (keyname) value (keynm)
        loop
    endif
    newkey=akey+1
    update main!idkeys set keyvalue=newkey where keyname=keynm and keyvalue=akey
    if _tally=1
        lDone=.t.
    endif
enddo
if not empty(cOldSelect)
    select &cOldSelect
else
    select 0
endif
return newkey
```

In a separate stored procedure, I have tried the following to isolate the key word `regional`:

```
FUNCTION GetHello

regional hello

RETURN "HELLO WORLD"
```

Which seems to work (for example, setting the default value of a column to `GetHello()` then running an insert over OLEDB).

The following causes my stored procedure to fail with "Feature is not available" over OLEDB:

```
FUNCTION GetHello
LOCAL test
test="select * from customer"
&test
RETURN "hello"
```

Comment: Confirm that newid is a stored procedure in the database.

Comment: yes, newid is a stored procedure in the db

Comment: is there any code in the NewId() stored procedure that is not supported via OLEDB? Supported VFP commands are in the help file or here: http://www.yaldex.com/fox_pro_tutorial/html/30184b27-f6e5-4aa8-ac28-12188d9093f8.htm

Comment: Would you share the code of newid()?

Comment: updated with newid() code

Comment: And does newid() run correctly if called in the VFP environment rather than via OLEDB?

Comment: yes, runs fine in VFP environment, fails in OLEDB

Comment: I'm really suspicious of the line that begins regional. To the best of my knowledge, regional is not a VFP keyword.

Comment: Tamar, I respectfully refer you to the Hacker's Guide To Visual Foxpro 6, page 700 :)

Comment: see edited post, it appears that OLEDB does not like running macro substitutions in stored procedures.

Comment: & is unfortunately abused a lot amongst Foxpro developers :( In fact it is needed in only very few places. Anyway I replaced that part with a simpler one.

Comment: Yeah, I had a vague memory that it had something to do with FP2.x screen sets. Regardless, it's not supported in VFP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the SP code! It shows what was the culprit.

Though my nerves tend to do many corrections on that code I will only modify enough to make it work from both VFP and C#:

```
function newId
parameter thisdbf
regional keynm, newkey, nOldSelect, lDone
keynm=padr(upper(thisdbf),50)
nOldSelect=select()
lDone=.f.
do while not lDone
    select keyvalue from main!idkeys where keyname=keynm into array akey
    if _tally=0
        insert into main!idkeys (keyname) value (keynm)
        loop
    endif
    newkey=akey+1
    update main!idkeys set keyvalue=newkey where keyname=keynm and keyvalue=akey
    if _tally=1
        lDone=.t.
    endif
enddo
Select (m.nOldSelect)
return newkey
```

*The changed part is only related to that `(if !empty(...)) block`.*

Comment: Thank you for your help Cetin!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this variable declaration line in the stored procedure:

```
regional keynm, newkey, cOldSelect, lDone
```

The 'regional' keyword is a holdover from the old FoxPro 2.6 for DOS\Windows. It was only used in programs generated by the screen builder tool. It obviously still lurks within Visual FoxPro to support functionality that migrates old FoxPro 2.6 projects to Visual FoxPro, because the code works fine in VFP. But the OLEDB driver doesn't support it.

Anyway, you need to change your stored procedure to use:

```
local keynm, newkey, cOldSelect, lDone
```

... and recompile it, for which you will need Visual FoxPro. Ensure there are no OLEDB or other connections to it and then in the Visual FoxPro command window:

```
compile c:\path\to\mydatabase.dbc
```

Comment: I tried replacing `regional` with `local` in the SP but no luck...How do I recompile the stored procedure in my db (main.DBC)? I edited it by right clicking and selecting "Edit stored procedures..."

Comment: Updated post with a working snippet using `regional`

Comment: It wouldn't harm, no need to change. The culprit code is where he tries to select previous work area (would that be ever empty?).